# Mobile browser not rendering at mobile size

Tags: html, mobile, cross-browser

I have a website that is built to change views depending on screen size. It wasn't doing so on my Android, ZTE Max using chrome. Instead, it was showing full sized window zoomed out very far.

I have read that I might want to use viewport meta tag, but I have also read this doesn't work on all mobile devices.

I want a solution for the big four. iPhone, Android, Windows, and BlackBerry.

I used the following...

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
```

And it works now on my mobile. Is this cross-browser(mobile) acceptable??
Is there a better solution(besides making a full mobile version of a site?)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
```

You should also design your website to be responsive so that your layout would look good on very low to medium device resolutions such as 480x, 768px, etc. So if your main desktop-targeted sight has 4 columns and is 940px wide for example, you can't just dump these 4 columns on a 480px display with no zooming enabled. Use the above meta tag in conjunction with media queries. For a good example, see a few Bootstrap themes and see how this is done.

Comment: I've got the responsive design down. Been testing on pure browser resizing and keeping the code simple and clear has made it show the same on mobile as it would on a smaller desktop browser. I'll look into the media quieries. Thanks!